# Cast string to Date in R from a CSV

Tags: r, date, csv

Format a date from CSV into a date R can use.

I have a time series data file. I want to load it into R, and cast the Date column to be something usable by R. Can I specify the input format to `as.Date()`, or use another function that will correctly cast a Date such as 1/1/14?

In other languages I'm used to passing in a format string that tells the caster exactly how to format it, e.g. `toDate('1/1/1', '%d/%m/%y')`. I haven't found this function yet for R.

my_time_series.csv

```
Date    Value
1/1/14  123
1/2/14  128.56
1/3/14  129.14
1/4/14  130.13
1/5/14  137.97
1/6/14  141.05
1/7/14  141.35
1/8/14  142.14
1/9/14  142.14
1/10/14 149.89
```

Now I can import it into R:

```
$ R
> dat = read.csv("time series test.csv", header = TRUE)
> dat
      Date    Value
1   1/1/14 123.0000
2   1/2/14 128.5693
3   1/3/14 129.1474
4   1/4/14 130.1361
5   1/5/14 137.9758
6   1/6/14 141.0548
7   1/7/14 141.3517
8   1/8/14 142.1449
9   1/9/14 142.1479
10 1/10/14 149.8912
```

Ok now I need to format those dates as actual dates. The `as.Date()` casting function looks promising, but returns an incorrect date:

```
> as.Date('1/10/14')
[1] "0001-10-14"
```

So I searched for whether I can specify an input format for `as.Date()`, but it only has a second parameter `format` for the output format.

I tried to work around this in Excel before saving the CSV, but it doesn't have any formats that seem to work by default with `as.Date()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an idiot, was just typing in the wrong formatter. This works fine.

```
> as.Date('1/10/14', '%m/%d/%y')
[1] "2014-01-10"
```

So if I have any arbitrary date format in the future, just rearrange the format string.